# Specific ways of extracting paragraphs from text in java for comparison

Tags: java, regex, text, nlp, paragraph

I would like to create a set of rules, maybe sets of different approaches in order to extract paragraphs from general purpose text and compare them.
Trying to find some approaches, I found out that I could use:

- Delimeters
- Capitalization
- Non - standard characters
- Regex

But I would like some advice in order how to apply those, or if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: It's fairly easy to extract paragraphs with regex. The problem comes from defining what a _paragraph_ is. Look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: Use `.split("\\R{2,}")` to split a text into blocks of substrings between 2 or more linebreaks.

Comment: This does not seem to work, I'm getting an error.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\R{2,}
 ^

Comment: So, you are not using Java 8, use `.split("(?:\r?\n|\r){2,}")` then.